# Evaluating $\int_0^{2\pi}{r - a\cos\theta \above 1pt \sqrt{r^2 - 2ra\cos\theta + a^2}}d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to evaluate
$$\int_0^{2\pi}{r - a\cos\theta \above 1pt \sqrt{r^2 - 2ra\cos\theta + a^2}}d\theta,$$
where $r$ and $a$ are positive constants such that $r<a$.

I've looked at tables of integrals, but I can't find the corresponding form.

Comment: looks like a total derivative to me... $\partial_r(r^2-2r a \cos(\theta)+a^2)^{1/2}=?$

Comment: I feel like this is is nested in a double or triple integral. If there is also an integral over $dr$, please provide that also.

Comment: Do you know complex analysis?

Comment: um... I didn't study complex analysis

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the Poisson integral formula:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoissonIntegral.html